# Type number in command prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt

when I'm trying to type number in command prompt (I'm trying to type "python3", it shows characters instead of number like this "pythonê"
[command-prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXv6R.png)
I don't know how to fix this and type an ordinal number. Anyone can help me with this problem? I really appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Clearly something is weird with your Windows setup. Since you haven't even gotten Python started, you don't have a Python problem. You should ask somewhere like SuperUser, and make sure to include the Windows tag (and get rid of the Python one).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you keybord input language not set to US/US format change the input language

Referece : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/258824/how-to-change-your-keyboard-layout